# TYPO3 delete feusers

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I use TYPO3 v8.7

Can I delete an FE-User like this or is there more to it?

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_DELETEquery(
  'fe_users',
  'uid = '.$user["uid"]
);

Comment: If your sole purpose is to delete the record from the database, then you can do it like this. But perhaps your real goal is something else? Could you elaborate what you really want to accomplish?

Comment: I agree with Dmitry's comment but in any case you should avoid the deprecated `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` and use the Doctrine-based API instead: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/BasicCrud/Index.html#delete-a-row

Comment: I would like to check regularly when the last login. After a certain time this should be deleted from the database. I'm from Germany. There is strong privacy by not being able to set deleted = 1.

Comment: @Mathias Brodala, thank you. I will change it.

Comment: it depends on your data. if you have related records you need to clean up. for this it might be better to 'delete' the record with the datahandler which cleans all relations to other records. afterwards you might do a hard delete on the `fe_users`record.